# Python - How to read a set of images and put it in a matrix?

Tags: python, image-processing, face-recognition, pca

I need to read a set of images in python using and put it into a matrix to be able to preform PCA (principle component analysis). All the images are in one folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `numpy` and `PIL`:

```
import numpy as np
import Image

dirname = '...'
[np.asarray(Image.open(os.path.join(dirname, fn))) for fn in os.listdir(dirname)]
```

Comment: NameError: name 'np' is not defined

Comment: it gives this error
NameError: name 'np' is not defined

Comment: sorry for my many questions as I am new to python
it gives me this error

Comment: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '10.pgm'

Comment: @user2229953: cleaned up my code.